Icon sometimes doesn't show on context menu shell extension
I try to add a shell extension for my app and show appTile as icon on it when I right click media files.I find a good sample ContextMenuSample. I just do some minor changes in ExplorerCommandVerb.cpp. But sometimes icon cannot show on context menu.

When icon shows, I click "Show more options", there is always a blank icon. I click it, it can trigger my app.


When icon doesn't show on shell extension, I click it, it couldn't trigger my app.And I click "Show more options", the shell extension disappears. Somehow,I cannot reproduce it at this moment. But this problem happened for times.


I get the icon like the following. Is there anything wrong? My project is here
IFACEMETHODIMP GetIcon(IShellItemArray* /* psiItemArray */, LPWSTR* ppszIcon){
    retValue = GetAppPathFromRegistry();
    std::wstring regPath = retValue + L"\\Images\\SmallTile.scale-200.png";
    std::filesystem::path currentPath = std::filesystem::current_path();
    
    iconPath = regPath;
    *ppszIcon = const_cast<LPWSTR>(iconPath.c_str());
    return S_OK;}


You seem to be using .png files for icons. are you sure it's supported? IExplorerCommand::GetIcon (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-iexplorercommand-geticon) stipulates "The retrieved icon resource string is in the standard format, for instance "shell32.dll,-249"."

@SimonMourier I have thought that it can be any format. I integrated .ico into dll and use resource id. It works well. Thanks a lot

@SimonMourier one more question, is it possible to add wildcard in itemtype in appxmanifest when I filter what type of files should shell extension display? Since I want to enable shell extension for pictures,audio,and video files, there are tens of formats totally like jpg,png,mp3,mp4 etc. Adding itemtype for each of them may have performace issue?? I know there are some subkey under \HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations like image or audio. I can create subkey under them to enable shell extension, but in this way shell extension can only display after user click "Show more options".

You should first answer this question if you solved it and then ask another one. As for this question, not sure there's a better way than what you describe (don't worry about performance)

@SimonMourier Yes, currently I have solved all problems. Just try to find a better way to filter file types

According to Simon Mourier's suggestion:
According to the Doc:IExplorerCommand::GetIcon method

The retrieved icon resource string is in the standard format, for
instance "shell32.dll,-249".

You could integrate .ico into dll and use resource id.
